# UIBarButton not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

I am learning Objective-C and I am trying to add UIBarButtonItem programmatically. I do it like this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(addGuest)];
```

and I have a function to be called when it is pressed.

```
- (void)addGuest{

}
```

But the bar button is not visible in navigation bar.

Comment: The code you provided is fine. It works in my demo project. Make sure you didn't make any other settings in StoryBoard.

Comment: Just tested your code and it works fine. Are you sure you are calling this code in the correct view controller? (direct child of the navigation controller)

Comment: I'm calling it in viewDidLoad of a TableViewController. And in storyboard I embedded the TableViewController in Navigation Bar, but I can't see the bar button

Comment: That should work. Have you checked that the colour of the menu item is not the same as the navigation bar background?

Comment: No, I haven't. How to check that?

Comment: Just set the background colour of the navigation bar to a bright red in storyboard and see if the menu item show up

Comment: I couldn't set the color of the navbar, so I wrote NSLog(@"asdasa") in viewDidLoad and it didn't print

Comment: I think I solved it. I didn't set a custom class in storyboard

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add" 
                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                            target:self 
                            action:@selector(addGuest:)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:item animated:YES];
```

Comment: check once your navigationItem is disable or not in current VC

Comment: The result is the same. I still can't see the bar button

Comment: did you embed your vc in navigationController? 
or does your vc push to tabbarController ?

Answer (score 0):

I have awesome solution u can use this and just call this method in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   [self DoneBtn];

 }
 //BarButton With Image no titleText on right handside

-(void)DoneBtn{

for (UIButton*obj in [self.navigationController.navigationBar subviews]) {

    if(obj.tag==1008){

        [obj removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
UIButton *Notification  = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35 , 35)];
[Notification setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BellIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[Notification addTarget:self action:@selector(NotificationBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:Notification];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rightBarButtonItem];

rightBarButtonItem=nil;

//BarButton With Image no titleText on left handside

UIButton *Profile  = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35 , 35)];
[Profile setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ProfileIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[Profile addTarget:self action:@selector(ProfileBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *LeftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:Profile];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:LeftBarButtonItem];

LeftBarButtonItem=nil;

}

//BarButton With titleText no image

UIButton *Notification  = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100 , 35)];

NSString*titleName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Notification"];
[Notification setTitle:titleName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[Notification setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[Notification addTarget:self action:@selector(NotificationBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:Notification];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rightBarButtonItem];

rightBarButtonItem=nil;
```

Comment: Pretty awesome buttons